# Pacemaker: migrate resource without adding a "prefer" line in config

Tags: migration, resources, pacemaker

Using pacemaker in a 2 nodes master/slave configuration.
In order to perform some tests, we want to switch the master role from *node1* to *node2*, and vice-versa. For instance if the current master is *node1*, doing

```
# crm resource migrate r0 node2
```

does indeed move the resource to *node2*. Then, ideally,

```
# crm resource migrate r0 node1
```

would migrate back to *node1*. The problem is that *migrate* added a line in the configuration to perform the switch

```
location cli-prefer-r0 r0 role=Started inf: node2
```

and in order to migrate back I have first to remove that line...

Is there a better way to switch master from one node to the other?

Comment: Have you tried moving the resource instead of migrating?

Comment: Do you have active/active or active/passive setup? if it is active/active you can just bring one node to standby and check if the resources are moved to the other node.

Comment: @YoMismo Active/passive. What is the difference between *migrate* and *move*?

Comment: It's been a long time since I had my cluster running, I've been checking crm's man page and migrate/move appear to be equivalent, but http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-plugin/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/ch06s08.html uses moving instead of migrating, for documentation I would use clusterlabs, since it is (or was when I set my cluster up) project's main page. If you have active/passive then it is easy for you, activate the second node and put in standby the first one, resources will have to move automatically. Have you checked the documentation? http://clusterlabs.org/doc/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this bit old; but it seems like no one answered this satisfactorily, and the requester never posted if his problem was solved or not.
So here is an explanation.

When you perform:

```
# crm resource migrate r0 node2
```

a `cli-prefer-*` rule is created.

Now when you want to move the r0 back to node1, you don't do:

```
# crm resource migrate r0 node1
```

but you perform:

```
# crm resource unmigrate r0
```

Using `umigrate` or `unmove` gets rid of
the `cli-prefer-*` rule automatically.

If you try to delete this rule manually in cluster config, really bad things happen in cluster, or at least bad things happened in my case.

Comment: I know this is quite old, but what "bad things" happened when you deleted the rule? Does using "unmigrate" move the resource to another node, or just cleanly remove the prefer rules?

Comment: Unmigrate removes the location constraint that is keeping a given resource from running on the "migrated from" node - it does not perform any move operations of its own, but just make them possible. If a resource has a preference for that node, it will try to move back if ordering/collocation constraints allow the resource to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Oh the joys.

This all boiled down to wether using `migrate` commands with or without target nodes. From the current cli documentation via `crm resource help migrate`:

> If the destination node is left out, the resource is migrated by
>   creating a constraint which prevents it from running on the current
>   node. For this type of constraint to be created, the force argument is
>   required.

In the past this could also be done without `force`, and when you ran a two-node-cluster (two nodes never constitute a proper cluster but lets not digress here), you ended up with a statement in pacemakers running config telling it explicitly to not run on the node it ran on when the `migrate` command was fired, so pacemaker would force it to move away onto another node.

If you ran a `crm resource migrate` you ended up with a `location cli-...` statement up in your pacemaker config. There are two types of such statements, which can be checked for rather easily:

```
crm configure show | grep -e cli-prefer -e cli-ban
```

For serious business, the command above should also be part of nagios/icinga/whatever monitoring check, as these manual constraints should never be present in running configuration in the long term anyway.

If you migrated again back to another node, you ended up with yet another such statement, marking the last node ALSO as a "non-runnable" location for the resource. If you had eventually all your nodes 'outmigrated' in such fashion... your resource in question would not start anywhere and you were out of luck, which is likely the reason this question was asked in the first place.

Solution was to ALWAYS have an `crm resource migrate` command being followed by an `crm resource unmigrate` command when omitting target nodes, to not shoot yourself in the foot eventually later.

---

If you however always specify a target node, all this does not matter:

Upon rerunning a `crm resource migrate RESOURCE NODE` / `pcs resource move RESOURCE NODE` the `cli-prefer...` statement within the pacemaker config gets adjusted, so no worries.

So you can run `crm resource migrate` / `pcs resource move` as often as you like without running into trouble of resources not being able to start anymore.

To get rid of any of these manual constraints for a resource in particular, run one of these:

```
crm resource unmigrate RESOURCE
crm resource clear RESOURCE

pcs resource clear RESOURCE
```

This however will not make your resources magically to their intial hosts, if you did not create location constraints in the first place - unlike the other answer here suggests.

Comment: In recent crm `crm configure show cli-\*` also works (no need for `grep -e cli-prefer -e cli-ban`).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to remove those `cli-prefer` constraints manually before you try to migrate back, or (if you don't care about inactive constraints lingering around) add a time period like 5 minutes:

```
crm resource migrate r0 node2 PT5M
```

After 5 minutes the rule is no longer effective (and `r0` might migrate back), but it is still visible.

Also note that in a two-node cluster you do not need to specify the other node.